# Build to style tag using webpack

Tags: css, webpack

In my webpack project, I want to inject styles as a `<style>` tag into the page, using JavaScript, rather than referencing an external file via a `<link>` tag. I am using [`style-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/style-loader) for styles currently, and it outputs a bunch of link tags in the head.

Rather than this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/things">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/things">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/things">
  </head>
  <body>
```

I want this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <style>
    /* things here */
  </style>
  <body>
```

Is there any way of doing this?  I had a read of the [documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html) but it only mentions building CSS output files, not outputting to a style tag in this way.

Reasons:

1. I am publishing a module to be included via NPM/Bower, and I would rather keep the build as a single package, rather than having to revert to
2. It is faster.  There is a lot of literature around minimising the number of requests, including from webpack:  https://github.com/christianalfoni/react-webpack-cookbook/wiki/Inlining-images

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that adding the loaders to the imports manually does the trick. Removing this loaders definition from the webpack config:

```
 module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style!css!sass!']
    }]
}
```

and adding manually to each style import:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'style!css!sass!./fieldList.scss'; // -> this line

class FieldList extends React.Component
```

This causes the styles to be injected in my preferred way.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use second entry point for styles.
All styles will be loaded first and then added to `<style>` tags in `<head>` section.

webpack.config.js:

```
export default {
  entry: {
    app: ['./app'],
    styles: ['./styles']
  },
  loaders: [{
    test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
    loaders: [
      'style',
      'css',
      'autoprefixer?browsers=last 3 versions',
      'sass'
    ]
  }]
}
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="styles.js"/>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="app.js"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  This is what I want to do as well, but when I moved the transforms to the `loader` config it used `<link>` tags again.  Currently unsure why that is.

Comment: Additionally, as your answer comments on my answer, as it currently stands it would be better as a comment on my answer, rather than a new answer.  I recommend you modify your answer to be more self-contained.